# Multi-Tenant ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, middleware, dbcontext

How would you configure the middleware to change the DBContext connection string based on a sub-domain of the income request?

It appears that the DBContext is set in the `Startup`... which looks too early to determine the HTTPRequest to resolve the connection string.

Comment: You could take a look at https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe it's a ASP.NET Core multi-tenant web application foundation with management for sites, users, roles, claims and more.

Comment: Although it hasn't been updated in a while I found this project very helpful in getting going with multi-tenant using a different DB connection per tenant. https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit

Answer (score 3):

Well, this might not suit your needs entirely, but here's what I would do:

Create a `DbContextFactory` class. This `DbContextFactory` class can create instances of the `DbContext` and can pass in any string to the `DbContext` constructor. Then inject this factory and whenever you need an instance of the dbcontext, just ask the factory to return one for you. Of course you have to manage the lifetime of the created contexts yourself (i.e. using block).

Another option can be to create the `DbContextFactory` so that it holds an instance of a `DbContext`. When you ask for a context object from the factory, the factory creates a new one and also stores it in a private field, and subsequent calls return that same instance. Make the factory `IDisposable` and in its `Dispose()` method, dispose the context as well. This way you don't have to worry about managing lifetime (if you use a Scoped registration).